# Assets files not loading in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i am using Laravel 4
my base url is `http://localhost/messifan/fms/laravel/public/`

my css in `public/css/barcelona.css`

browser trying to load this URL

```
http://localhost/messifan/fms/laravel/public/css/barcelona.css
```

i am using this code in view to load css

```
<?php echo URL::asset('css/barcelona.css'); ?>
```

I get this error trying to open `http://localhost/messifan/fms/laravel/public/css/barcelona.css`

[image]

Comment: Do you still get this error if you try to access http://localhost/messifan/fms/laravel/public/css/barcelona.css in the browser?

Comment: yes. i get error in image when trying to css directly via url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be on your htaccess or permissions.

Try to temporarily remove htaccess and try to access directly the css file. If the problem persists then you should try to `chmod` `public/css` folder and the files in to 777 and try again.

Check again the path to the css file and its name.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php echo HTML::style('css/barcelona.css'); ?>
```

Edit
PS: This will load the styles.
To access the path to the file, you don't need to do much! well, unless you want to put the link to it in your view:

```
<a href="<?php echo URL::asset('css/barcelona.css'); ?>">The CSS File</a>
```